# owlexplanation with Hermit reasoner

Tags: java, eclipse, owl, ontology, owl-api

I am trying to use Hermit Reasoner to check consistency. Hermit reasoner by default does not provide any justification/explanations for the inconsistencies.

**EDITED VERSION:: I'm currently trying with OWLReasoner, but still it which throws an error.**

```
 import java.util.Set;

import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner;
import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.Explanation;
import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.ExplanationGeneratorFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.ExplanationManager;
import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.impl.blackbox.checker.InconsistentOntologyExplanationGeneratorFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.Node;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasoner;
import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.ExplanationGenerator;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLNamedIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasonerFactory;

public class ConsistencyChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OWLOntologyManager m=OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();

   OWLOntology o=m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(IRI.create("http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/isg/ontologies/UID/00793.owl"));

      // Reasoner hermit=new Reasoner(o);
        OWLReasoner owlreasoner=new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory().createReasoner(o);
        System.out.println(owlreasoner.isConsistent());

      //System.out.println(hermit.isConsistent());

        //---------------------------- Copied from example--------- 
        OWLDataFactory df = m.getOWLDataFactory();
        OWLClass testClass = df.getOWLClass(IRI.create("urn:test#testclass"));
        m.addAxiom(o, df.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(testClass, df.getOWLNothing()));
        OWLNamedIndividual individual = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI
                .create("urn:test#testindividual"));
        m.addAxiom(o, df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(testClass, individual));

        //----------------------------------------------------------

        Node<OWLClass> unsatisfiableClasses = owlreasoner.getUnsatisfiableClasses();
        //Node<OWLClass> unsatisfiableClasses = hermit.getUnsatisfiableClasses();
        for (OWLClass owlClass : unsatisfiableClasses) {
            System.out.println(owlClass.getIRI());
        }
        //-----------------------------
        ExplanationGeneratorFactory<OWLAxiom> genFac = ExplanationManager.createExplanationGeneratorFactory((OWLReasonerFactory) owlreasoner);
        ExplanationGenerator<OWLAxiom> gen = genFac.createExplanationGenerator(o);

        //-------------------------

        InconsistentOntologyExplanationGeneratorFactory igf = new InconsistentOntologyExplanationGeneratorFactory((OWLReasonerFactory) owlreasoner, 10000);
        //InconsistentOntologyExplanationGeneratorFactory igf = new InconsistentOntologyExplanationGeneratorFactory((OWLReasonerFactory) hermit, 10000);
        ExplanationGenerator<OWLAxiom> generator = igf.createExplanationGenerator(o);

        OWLAxiom entailment = df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(df.getOWLNothing(),
                individual);

        //-------------
        Set<Explanation<OWLAxiom>> expl = gen.getExplanations(entailment, 5);
        //------------

        System.out.println("Explanation "
                + generator.getExplanations(entailment, 5));
    }
}
```

The output is

```
true
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Nothing
http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#CheeseyVegetableTopping
http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#IceCream
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner cannot be cast to org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasonerFactory
    at ConsistencyChecker.main(ConsistencyChecker.java:82)
```

Any help in integrating owlexplanation api **[1]** with the Hermit Reasoner/OWLReasoner would be appreciated.

[1]https://github.com/matthewhorridge/owlexplanation

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
//package org.semanticweb.HermiT.examples;

import java.util.Set;

import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Configuration;
import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner;
import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.ReasonerFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasoner;

import com.clarkparsia.owlapi.explanation.BlackBoxExplanation;
import com.clarkparsia.owlapi.explanation.HSTExplanationGenerator;

public class Explanations {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // First, we create an OWLOntologyManager object. The manager will load and 
        // save ontologies. 
        OWLOntologyManager manager=OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        // We will create several things, so we save an instance of the data factory
        OWLDataFactory dataFactory=manager.getOWLDataFactory();
        // Now, we create the file from which the ontology will be loaded. 
        // Here the ontology is stored in a file locally in the ontologies subfolder
        // of the examples folder.
        //File inputOntologyFile = new File("examples/ontologies/pizza.owl");
        // We use the OWL API to load the ontology. 
        //OWLOntology ontology=manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(inputOntologyFile);
        // We use the OWL API to load the Pizza ontology.
        OWLOntology ontology=manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(IRI.create("http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/isg/ontologies/UID/00793.owl"));

        // Lets make things worth and turn Pizza into an inconsistent ontology by asserting that the 
        // unsatisfiable icecream class has some instance. 
        // First, create an instance of the OWLClass object for the unsatisfiable  icecream class.

        IRI icecreamIRI=IRI.create("http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#IceCream");
        OWLClass icecream=dataFactory.getOWLClass(icecreamIRI);

        // Now we can start and create the reasoner. Since explanation is not natively supported by 
        // HermiT and is realised in the OWL API, we need to instantiate HermiT 
        // as an OWLReasoner. This is done via a ReasonerFactory object. 
        ReasonerFactory factory = new ReasonerFactory();
        // We don't want HermiT to thrown an exception for inconsistent ontologies because then we 
        // can't explain the inconsistency. This can be controlled via a configuration setting.  
        Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
        configuration.throwInconsistentOntologyException=false;
        // The factory can now be used to obtain an instance of HermiT as an OWLReasoner. 
        OWLReasoner reasoner=factory.createReasoner(ontology, configuration);
        // Let us confirm that icecream is indeed unsatisfiable:
        System.out.println("Is icecream satisfiable? "+reasoner.isSatisfiable(icecream)); 
        System.out.println("Computing explanations...");
        // Now we instantiate the explanation classes
        BlackBoxExplanation exp=new BlackBoxExplanation(ontology, factory, reasoner);
        HSTExplanationGenerator multExplanator=new HSTExplanationGenerator(exp);
        // Now we can get explanations for the unsatisfiability. 
        Set<Set<OWLAxiom>> explanations=multExplanator.getExplanations(icecream);
        // Let us print them. Each explanation is one possible set of axioms that cause the 
        // unsatisfiability. 
        for (Set<OWLAxiom> explanation : explanations) {
            System.out.println("------------------");
            System.out.println("Axioms causing the unsatisfiability: ");
            for (OWLAxiom causingAxiom : explanation) {
                System.out.println(causingAxiom);
            }
            System.out.println("------------------");
        }
        // Let us make the ontology inconsistent to also get explanations for an 
        // inconsistency, which is slightly more involved since we dynamically 
        // have to change the factory constructor; otherwise, we can't suppress 
        // the inconsistent ontology exceptions that the OWL API requires a 
        // reasoner to throw.  
        // Let's start by adding a dummy individual to the unsatisfiable Icecream class. 
        // This will cause an inconsistency. 
        OWLAxiom ax=dataFactory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(icecream, dataFactory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create("http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#dummyIndividual")));
        manager.addAxiom(ontology, ax);
        // Let us confirm that the ontology is inconsistent
        reasoner=factory.createReasoner(ontology, configuration);
        System.out.println("Is the changed ontology consistent? "+reasoner.isConsistent());
        // Ok, here we go. Let's see why the ontology is inconsistent. 
        System.out.println("Computing explanations for the inconsistency...");
        factory=new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory() {
            protected OWLReasoner createHermiTOWLReasoner(org.semanticweb.HermiT.Configuration configuration,OWLOntology ontology) {
                // don't throw an exception since otherwise we cannot compte explanations 
                configuration.throwInconsistentOntologyException=false;
                return new Reasoner(configuration,ontology);
            }  
        };
        exp=new BlackBoxExplanation(ontology, factory, reasoner);
        multExplanator=new HSTExplanationGenerator(exp);
        // Now we can get explanations for the inconsistency 
        explanations=multExplanator.getExplanations(dataFactory.getOWLThing());
        // Let us print them. Each explanation is one possible set of axioms that cause the 
        // unsatisfiability. 
        for (Set<OWLAxiom> explanation : explanations) {
            System.out.println("------------------");
            System.out.println("Axioms causing the inconsistency: ");
            for (OWLAxiom causingAxiom : explanation) {
                System.out.println(causingAxiom);
            }
            System.out.println("------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Its just that back then we were not able to find the answer. The answer was actually found in the source code itself. Instead of deleting the question. We left the answer also tagged.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because you're casting an `OWLReasoner` to an `OWLReasonerFactory`.

The `OWLReasonerFactory` for HermiT is the one you've used a few lines above:

`new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory()`